# How to solve 2nd-order linear ODEs in matrix form by Mathematica?

Tags: differential-equations, equation-solving

How to solve a set of 2nd-order linear ODEs in matrix form by Mathematica? The ODEs are like,

$U''=AU+b$

where, $U=\{u_1(x),u_2(x),..,u_n(x)\}^T$, $b=px\{-1,0,...,0,1\}$ is another n-dimensional vector function of $x$, and $A=a*Tr$ is a $n\times n$ **tridiagonal matrix** with elements in the main diagonal of $Tr$ being -2 and those in the upper or lower diagnals of $Tr$ being -1.

How to solve it by mathmetica?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You did not give an example, so I made one up.

```
lhs  = {y1''[x],y2''[x]}
A    = {{1,0},{0,4}}
vars = {y1[x],y2[x]}
b    = {1,x}
eqs=Thread[lhs-A.vars==b]
```

And now just do

```
DSolve[eqs, vars, x]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

But typically one solves a set of first order ode's using matrix form. Not a set of second order ode's in Matrix form.

For coupled ode's let `A = {{1, 1}, {0, 4}}` and now the solution is

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Notice that first derivative does not enter in this system due to the way you set it up.

A better way is to covert your second order ode's to first order using state space formulation and then set up a system of first order odes in matrix form to solve.

Comment: `DSolve[y''[x] - {{1, 0}, {0, 4}} . y[x] == {1, x},  y \[Element] Vectors[2], x]` is shorter, I think from version 13

Comment: @Nasser the 1st order ODEs have been obtained as $V''=BV+f$, where $V=\{U,U'\}$ is a 2n-dimension vector, $B=\{\{0,I\},\{A,0\}\}$, and $f=\{0,b\}$.

Comment: @Nasser How to solve this using Mathematica? Is it possible to gain a genernal solution if n is pretty large?

Comment: @HC6 if the set of first order ode's are linear, then mma can solve it for sure, even if the system is coupled. It does not matter how many there are. But If they are non-linear, you might have to use numerical methods.  State space also support linear and nonlinear system.

Comment: @Nasser Thank you so much. One more question about the boundary conditions, please. I  solved this set of 1st-order odes with `DSolve[]` as mentioned by @rmw and a complicated general expression is obtained. However, when I try to prescribe the BCs with `Solve[]`, I don't know how to get the unknown coefficient $c_i$ in the genreal solution. they don't seem to equal `Subscript[c,i]`. For example, $c_1$ in the general solution doesn't equal `Subscript[c,1]`. If use `Subscript[c,1]` as the unknown in `Solve[]`, a void set will be obtain.

Comment: Why do you want to solve for constants yourself? why not let DSolve do it? i.e. add the BC into the DSolve command. That is what I would do.  If you get different answer using your method of solving for them later one, may be you did something wrong. You could post separate question on this and someone will try to find why/